# Check if strings in array includes a substring in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a string in an array:

```
string_array = ["firstname@domain.com.au", "lastname@domaintwo.com.au"]
domains = ["@domain.com.au", "firstname"]
```

and I need to remove any matches where the strings in the above array contains a substring from another array.

I've tried the below:

```
test = string_array.reject { |item| domains.include?(item) }
#=> ["firstname@domain.com.au", "lastname@domaintwo.com.au"]
```

It should be the other way around, right? something like

```
test = string_array.reject { |item| item.include?(domains) }
```

But that raises `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
string_array = ["firstname@domain.com.au", "lastname@domaintwo.com.au"]
domains = ["@domain.com.au", "firstname"]

string_array.reject { |email| domains.any? { |domain| email.include?(domain) } }
#=> ["lastname@domaintwo.com.au"]
```

The reason your version doesn't work, is because you compared a string with an array of strings. And because the exact substring is not included in the array, there is no match. Instead, you have to compare each string with it is a substring of any other string.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a regular expression matching all of your substrings via [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html#union-method) and then filter out anything that *doesn't* match via [`grep_v`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#grep_v-method):

```
string_array = ["firstname@domain.com.au", "lastname@domaintwo.com.au"]
domains = ["@domain.com.au", "firstname"]

string_array.grep_v(Regexp.union(domains))
#=> ["lastname@domaintwo.com.au"]
```

Note that instead of substrings you can also use other regular expressions with `Regexp.union`, e.g. `/@domain\.com\.au\z/` to make the domain only match at the end of a string (`\z` is Ruby's end-of-string [anchor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors))